# EF 4.3 config section

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

Hi I have the following in my web.config

```
 <entityFramework>
<contexts>
  <context type=" Dashboard.Domain.DataContext, Dashboard.Domain">
    <databaseInitializer type="Dashboard.Domain.DataContextInitializer, Dashboard.Domain" />
  </context>
</contexts>
```

the problem is that when I now try to scaffold via the gui tools in vs 2010 it throws a design time exception

> Unable to retrieve meta data for 'entity type' Failed to set database initlizer of type 'Init type goes here' specified in app config. see inner exception

why does this happen it also happened with the EF 4.1 way of defining the intializer in config.

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the inner exception too?

Comment: it may make zero difference here, but you do have a space after " :  type=" <--there"

Comment: tried the additional space, im not able to get the inner exception where does vs store internal exceptions... the windows eventlog I would have thought but dont see any related exceptions in there